# Is there a drawback to processing Sass to css with both debug info and sourcemap?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox-addon, sass

I was struggling to get Chrome to work with Sass because the sourcemap wasn't working. Took me a bit before I realized I wasn't generating a sourcemap using the `--debug-info` flag. So once I starting using the `--sourcemap` flag, `scss` worked fine in Chrome. But without the `debug-info` flag, FireSass no longer worked in Firefox. Turns out calling both flags works fine, but are the any drawbacks or anything to be weary of?

```
sass --watch --sourcemap --debug-in sass/screen.scss:screen.css
```

Comment: I found a drawback when using Git. The debug information has your user name in it, so you get a conflict on every line of the css. So it's best to do a clean build before commiting to a repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it probably takes a negligible amount longer, but basically, no.  I wouldn't worry.